# List of dictionary changes on assignment automatically

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, variable-assignment

I have populated a list of dicts by doing the below.

```
addrs=[]
for i in address:#got from another source in list of dicts form
    address1=i['str1']+" "+i['str2']+" "+str(i['city'])+" "+str(i['pinCode'])
    city=i['city']
    state=i['state']).lower()
    pincode=i['pinCode']
    addr_type="T01"
    addr={
          "TYPE": addr_type,
          "ADDRESS-1": address1,
          "CITY":city,
          "STATE": state,
          "PIN": str(pincode)
        }
    addrs.append(addr)
test['k1']['k2']['k3']=addrs
```

Once populated, I assigned this addrs to a key in test.

However, after the assignment to the key, when I print the test, I see that it has changed to dict of lists.

```
addrs={"TYPE": ["D01","D04"],
      "ADDRESS-1": ["NO.X XXX KRISHGIRI XXXXXX 635XXX","NO.X XXX KRISHGIRI XXXXXX 635XXX"],
      "CITY": ["XXX","XXX"],
      "STATE": ["XX","XX"],
      "PIN": ["635XXX","635XXX"]}
```

How did this happen? Is it because of the previously initiated datatype? I have changed to list/ dict/ string. None of this worked. I need the list of dicts to stay as it is even after assignment.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to provide a [mre].

Comment: Could you provide a bit more context? What operations did you make? Is `{'key1':['value1','value3'],'key2':['value2','value4']}` a result of `test['k1']['k2']['k3']` or the actual assignment?

Comment: @DanielLavedoniodeLima I have edited the question accordingly as requested.

Comment: Thanks, but you haven't showed where the variables `temp`, `address` and `type1` are instantiated. Still not totally clear for me.

Maybe what you want to know is that lists and dictionary are muttable objects, so if you reassign it to a new variable and changes it, you'll get the updated value. If that's what you're asking, I'll write a proper answer for that, but I'm not sure if that's the actual problem.

Comment: @DanielLavedoniodeLima values like address are got from another source in a list of dicts form. I know that lists and dicts are mutable objects. But what triggered the change from a list of dicts to a dict of lists.